# Elasticsearch aggregation order by top hit score

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to order buckets by doc.score of top_hit. My current implementation is below.

```
  group_by_iid: {
    terms: {
      field: 'iid',
      order: { max_score: 'desc' },
      size: 0
    },
    aggs: {
      max_score: { max: { script: 'doc.score' } },
      top_hit: {
        top_hits: {
          sort: [{ source_priority: { order: 'desc' } }],
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is wrong because buckets are ordered by their top score, not their top source_priority document's score. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the way I resolved it was to introduce a sub-aggregation on the docs score.  Then in my outer aggregation, I ordered by name of the max_score aggregation.

`GET /my-index/my-type/_search`

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "searchTerm": {
              "query": "style",
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "flt_field": {
            "searchTerm": {
              "like_text": "style"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_target_url": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "targetUrl",
        "order": {
          "max_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I followed the directions on this link:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: If your documents happen to have a "score" field and you want a metrics aggregation like "max" to work with the score computed by elasticsearch rather than the document-defined one, the script in the aggregation should be "_score", not "doc.score".

Comment: @Shadocko yes!  that's pretty misleading.  Thanks for the comment.  I'm trying out the same example and now it works.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it with partitions? My question is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484351/elasticsearch-aggregation-order-by-top-hit-score-with-partitions

Comment: @Roy, if you can update your answer to replace doc.score to _score. It will save few minutes for people who are not reading the comments. +1